# How to use D3D12GetDebugInterface API from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, com, directx, direct3d

I am currently trying to use Direct3D from c# and I've started by using the D3D12GetDebugInterface API.
The C++ syntax of the function is as follows (copied from the Microsoft documentation):

```
HRESULT D3D12GetDebugInterface(
    REFIID riid,
    void   **ppvDebug
);
```

I'm having trouble importing the function into C#. I thought that maybe riid should be a pointer to a Guid struct, and I'm just using an IntPtr for **ppvDebug. Since **ppvDebug is a pointer to a pointer to an ID3D12Debug interface, I tried reimplementing the ID3D12Debug interface in C# code and using Marshal.PtrToStructure() to resolve the IntPtr to a usable ID3D12Debug interface instance, but that won't work. I remember reading about the ID3D12Debug interface being a COM object, but don't you need an ID for a COM object so you can import it? I haven't found any sort of COM ID anywhere in the documentation.

Anyway here's my latest attempt at getting something out of the function:

```
[DllImport("D3D12.dll")]
static extern int D3D12GetDebugInterface(IntPtr riid, IntPtr ppvDebug);

void func() {
    unsafe
    {
        IntPtr DebugControllerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        Type InterfaceType = typeof(ID3D12Debug);
        Guid ID = InterfaceType.GUID;
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Guid));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(ID, ptr, false);

        D3D12GetDebugInterface(ptr, DebugControllerPtr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        ID3D12Debug DebugController = null;
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(DebugControllerPtr, DebugController);
        DebugController.EnableDebugLayer();
    }
}
```

In case you want to see my ID3D12Debug interface:

```
interface ID3D12Debug
{
    void EnableDebugLayer();
}
```

As I said, I think Direct3D makes use of COM, which I am completely missing here, so maybe that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are usually many ways to declare interop code. Here is one that should work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    D3D12GetDebugInterface(typeof(ID3D12Debug).GUID, out var obj);
    var debug = (ID3D12Debug)obj;
    debug.EnableDebugLayer(); // for example
}

[DllImport("D3D12")]
public static extern int D3D12GetDebugInterface([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppvDebug);

[Guid("344488b7-6846-474b-b989-f027448245e0"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ID3D12Debug
{
    [PreserveSig]
    void EnableDebugLayer();
}
```

- You must add interface Guid and InterfaceType attributes for COM interfaces.
- Guid can be passed easily by reference using `UnmanagedType.LPStruct`
- You don't need unsafe code here.
- You should check for errors (undone in my code)
- If you need .NET interface definitions with DirectX, you can use this open source project here: https://github.com/smourier/DirectN, for example: https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/blob/master/DirectN/DirectN/Generated/ID3D12Debug.cs

Comment: Error checking is easy, add `PreserveSig = false` to the dllimport attribute, and change the return type from int to void. The runtime will then do the right thing automagically, i.e. marshal failed HRESULT into exceptions.

Comment: @Soonts - Never said it was hard, just said it wasn't done, and I was more talking about D3D12GetDebugInterface return code. I don't like raising exceptions sometimes for legit errors. I prefer not to raise exceptions but test errors myself, hence the PreserveSig attribute. In this particular case the function does return void, so the PreserveSig is here to show intent.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about the GUID tag on the interface definition? Did you get it from somewhere or did you generate it yourself?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa - The guid is located in Windows SDK's d3d12sdklayers.h file. Or use this (other) tool of mine: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=ID3D12Debug*

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks a lot. One more question: What exactly does the PreserveSig attribute in the interface definition do?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa - here nothing special. It usually tells .net not to be smart and raise exceptions if the method returns a negative code (HRESULT usually), but instead returns what's returned as is. Check the official doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @SimonMourier What's the point of writing the attribute in there? Doesn't it default to just passing the HRESULT value back to you? Can I leave it out?